# Is there a way to relocate LVs from an un-partitioned disk to a partition on another disk?

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

Freshly signed up newb here, apologies in advance for any silliness and wordiness.

(Also excuse the makeshift formatting; ssh is not enabled on my build yet, and my company has copy-paste disabled in vSphere).

Been grinding pretty hard at my *nix education over the past year or two, and engineering at work has enough faith in me now apparently to have tasked me with an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS lab test VM on our vCenter to ensure that we can support it properly.

Here's some additional details on the issue.

When I booted the ISO, I set up partitioning manually, as per policy. Our current standard is 16 (hence my project to test 18.04), but to complicate things further our documentation is even older than that; version 14. Notably, the boot/installation process seems markedly different between the two versions.

This was the partition plan used:

```
/boot -512 MB                                -N/A - This must be physical

/     -5120 MB                               -lv_root

/var  -5120 MB                               -lv_var

/home -1024 MB                               -lv_home

/tmp  -3072 MB                               -lv_tmp

swap  -1 x RAM with a maximum of 4096 MB     -lv_swap

/free -All remaining free space.             -lv_free
```

So initially, I set the VM up with a single disk. However, I noticed that whenever I chose to add a partition to this disk during setup, the option to set LVM became grayed out. The reverse was also true - setting up LVM negated the option to partition the disk. What I eventually did to work around this was simply make two disks, one very small one to mount /boot on, and another much larger one for everything else.

The other issue is that I'm not intending for swap to mounted the way it is. But there was no option in the OS setup that allowed for anything other than "/swap".

What I've wound up with is the following:

```
sda                    disk
|-sda1                 part
|-sda2                 part /boot
sdb                    disk
|-system_vg_lv_root    lvm  /
|-system_vg_lv_var     lvm  /var
|-system_vg_lv_home    lvm  /home
|-system_vg_lv_tmp     lvm  /tmp
|-system_vg_lv_swap    lvm  /swap
|-system_vg_lv_free    lvm  /free
```

And what I need is this:

```
sda                       disk
|-sda1                    part /boot
|-sda2                    part 
   |-system_vg_lv_root    lvm  /
   |-system_vg_lv_var     lvm  /var
   |-system_vg_lv_home    lvm  /home
   |-system_vg_lv_tmp     lvm  /tmp
   |-system_vg_lv_swap    lvm  [SWAP]
   |-system_vg_lv_free    lvm  /free
```

And I'm not sure how I can fix this without completely rebuilding the VM from scratch, which I'd really love to avoid. I'm hoping there is a way to unmount the entire vg from sdb and then expand the sda disk in vSphere, add that space to sda1 or sda2 and then put the vg back. That and I need to know what I'm doing wrong with swap. I need it mounted as [SWAP], not /swap, and I know how to do that, but it doesn't help if the entire vg is still taking up its own disk.

Is this fixable? And if I do need to rebuild the OS, is there a step I misread that I can revisit to avoid this in the future?